# How to execute dynamic MongoDB commands in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

For a special case, I need to dynamically construct various MongoDB driver calls, e.g

```
comand = "db.collection.find({name: "doe"})"
```

which must then be passed to the mongodb driver, e.g.

```
var db = MongoClient.connect("mongodb://..../test");
var result = eval(command);
console.log(result)
```

I have tried `db.eval()`, `eval()` and `runCommand()` without success.

How can this be done?

Comment: I'm going to ask anyway: why do you need this? Regardless, you should probably read up on how asynchronous operations work in Node.

Comment: The business case forces us to do a kind of pre-definied transactions on the servers, which are constructed on the fly. You may compare it roughly with stored procedures on DB2 or MS SQL.

The eval() statement will of course be enclosed and added with a callback routine.

Comment: What we need is the same functionality as the shell provides, e.g.

    mongo --eval "db.anyName.anyAPI()"

but in a Node.js application,

Comment: So why doesn't `db.eval()` work for you, specifically? Did you take a look [at the example code](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Db.html#eval)?

Comment: It works! Sorry, I had quite some trouble with the db.eval() syntax. Now everything is fine.
Thank you for your support!

Comment: db.eval() is deprecated as on MongoDB 3.2 and forward